Are POST error LEDs standard?
I recently picked up a motherboard off AliExpress which has a POST display.

I'm still waiting on some parts to finish up my build, but I'm wondering if the display on the top right is a 'standard' - or there's what I need  to look up what the codes it shows are. I'm hoping it'll boot right up so I can check the specs, but I'm a little away from that. I found this site that references building a POST diagnostics card (which would be similar?) which indicates its specific to brand but is also ~20 years old, and links to Usenet.
I found manuals for ISA based POST diagnosis cards - this seems to be an old one, which has different codes by manufacturer, and this possibly newer one that does not
There's no manual for the actual motherboard as far as I know, and I'll be happy to update details like what UEFI/BIOS it uses, once I can bring it up.

In my experience the error codes are entirely dependent on who wrote the firmware (UEFI).

@Ramhound I was under the impression these got done via the LPC - that its UEFI implementation specific would be useful but this is one of those places where I can't really get 'good' docs on quickly, and would be useful to document in general.

Do you know which UEFI implementation? AMI as an example.

Not yet. I'm still waiting on a heatsink before I can boot it up. I mean in theory modernish x86 should throttle, but that's a risk I'd rather not take

Finally managed to get the heatsink but its too tall. ANYWAY, this one has an aptio bios

Getting the machine running got me a few useful data points - for AMI/Aptio UEFI implementations at least, they're standard. Asus called them Q codes, and they're identical between their X99, X299 and X399 motherboards - so the codes are identical between intel and AMD platforms. This list matches perfectly to the list for chinese motherboards, and an AMI reference list maintained by Miyconst here.
The Board I have is identified as a C612 chipset - and the boot processes shows some of the codes listed in the AMI reference - code 19 for example. You will also see a USB hotplug code B4.
I also verified this with no ram (code 55), and the machine will throw a fit at you if there's nothing bootable in the system (AE).
I think in general if you have one of these LEDs, its probably a safe option to look up the code for a x99 board, and there's a significant chance a undocumented board will be using the same codes.
